Running CIS Benchmark broke my connection to the Internet?
On my Ubuntu machine, after running the CIS Benchmark, I can no longer connect to the Internet.

The solution was the CIS Benchmark broke my DNS. I had to to set up my firewall rules like this. Note the closing brace in the very bottom left!

Then, running
sudo su
systemctl restart nftables 
exit

solved my problem.

please remove the picture of the text and replace it with the text
